# Removing Mouseovers

Tags: javascript, events, mouseover

I'm not a programmer, I just know enough to get by.  Someone that was once in our group made a bookmarklet to remove mouseovers from the app we use.  It broke and now we can't do it.  I looked into the page that we want to remove the mouseovers and found:

```
// disable mouseovers for now - MSIE doesn't behave when you trigger a mouseover before page is loaded
var OLgateOK=0;
// enable mouseovers once page has loaded
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() { OLgateOK=1; });
```

I believe that I can use an eventblock or prevent, but I'm not sure.  on top of that I'm not sure on how to refresh the page via the bookmarklet or if that just happens.

I'm guessing that this is a simple thing to prevent the mouseovers, I just don't know enough to figure it out...Any help would be great.

edit:  Sadly the website is behind a firewall that you can not get to.  I looked and I don't think that I can get to the "code" as the vendor of the app does not like to share.  Thank you for looking at it. I'm just going to have to dig in some more and just trial and error it...

Comment: The code you have shown depends significantly upon *exactly* how the app you are using is written (it appears to be clearing a flag which the other code depends upon). To solve this problem, we need to see that code. Please [edit] the question to provide that code and an example page on which it is used: (code in the question and at least a link to a page where it is currently displaying mouseovers). While we can guess at what you are using by [Googling `OLgateOK`](https://www.google.com/search?q=OLgateOK), we can not know if one of those results is the code you are *currently* using.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use the `removeEventListener` method - see [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)